# State Space Model Basics

Tags: control, control-system, state-space

I have added the problem with its solution.
[image]
I tried applying Mason's Gain Formula which led me to the same result and it should have as Transfer Function is unique.

[image]

Is there a shorter way to get Transfer Function similar to the below trick we have for Companion form or through some other manipulation ?

[image]

Comment: I think the solution provided by the book above is the most trivial and simplest way to arrive at transfer function from a state space matrix.

Comment: But in case of higher order like 3or4, there will be lot of calculation involved.

Comment: Yes for higher orders, it's out of the scope to do using pen and paper